# How to parse wcf ksoap2 response that returns List<List<string>> android

Tags: c#, android, wcf, android-ksoap2, arrayofstring

I have a wcf ksoap2 service that returns List> as response. Now I have to parse this response

```
anyType

{

ArrayOfstring=anyType

{
string=Wireless; string=Access Wireless; string=anyType{}; string=anyType{}; string=00001; string=--;
};

ArrayOfstring=anyType
{
string=Wireless; string=Airlink; string=anyType{}; string=anyType{}; string=00003; string=--;
};

ArrayOfstring=anyType
{
string=Long Distance; string=Nobel LD GOT Africa; string=anyType{}; string=anyType{}; string=NBLDAF; string=--;
};

ArrayOfstring=anyType
{
string=Long Distance; string=STI LD Smash; string=anyType{}; string=anyType{}; string=00028; string=--;
};

ArrayOfstring=anyType
{
string=International TopUp; string=Afghanistan Etisalat Top-Up $2-$75; string=Hussain; string=0345339; string=ETIAFG; string=--;
};

ArrayOfstring=anyType
{
string=International TopUp; string=Afghanistan Etisalat Top-Up $2-$75; string=Hussain; string=0345339; string=ETIAFG; string=--;
}; 

ArrayOfstring=anyType
{
string=International TopUp; string=Bolivia Viva Top-Up $5 - $75; string=Hussain; string=0345339; string=VIVABO; string=--; 
}; 

ArrayOfstring=anyType
{
string=International TopUp; string=Bolivia Viva Top-Up $5 - $75; string=Hussain; string=0345339; string=VIVABO; string=--; 
}; 

ArrayOfstring=anyType
{
string=International TopUp; string=Peru Movistar Top-Up  $5 - $75; string=Hussain; string=0345339; string=anyType{}; string=--;
};

}
```

I know how to parse a response that returns List. I was using this code

```
HttpTransportSE htp = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            htp.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelop);

            response = (SoapObject) soapEnvelop.getResponse();

            if (response != null) {

                if (response.getPropertyCount() > 0) {
                    InternationalTopup.arr_Items = new String[response
                            .getPropertyCount()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
                        InternationalTopup.arr_Items[i] = response.getProperty(
                                i).toString();

                    }
                }
            }
```

but I have no idea how to parse the above response.
Do i have to use Json?
Please provide some examples and share your experience. 
Any help will be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you service built on WCF and if you can return json, then you don't need to use KSoap. There's a detail example, in my blog. [Please refer this](http://rakitech.wordpress.com/2013/04/30/accessing-wcf-service-via-android-wcf-ef-4-1-sqlserver-2008-r2-android-gson/)